# Adding a print statement changes model inference

Tags: python, pytorch

I am dealing with an extremely weird bug in an inference loop (a modified timm inference loop, the model is a pretrained ‘convnext_xlarge_in22ft1k’):

```
import os
import time
import argparse
import logging
import numpy as np
import torch

from timm.models import create_model, apply_test_time_pool
from timm.data import ImageDataset, create_loader, resolve_data_config

torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
_logger = logging.getLogger('inference')


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch ImageNet Inference')
parser.add_argument('data', metavar='DIR',
                    help='path to dataset')
parser.add_argument('--model', '-m', metavar='MODEL', default='dpn92',
                    help='model architecture (default: dpn92)')
parser.add_argument('-j', '--workers', default=4, type=int, metavar='N',
                    help='number of data loading workers (default: 2)')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch-size', default=256, type=int,
                    metavar='N', help='mini-batch size (default: 256)')
parser.add_argument('--input-size', default=None, nargs=3, type=int,
                    metavar='N N N', help='Input all image dimensions (d h w, e.g. --input-size 3 224 224), uses model default if empty')
parser.add_argument('--interpolation', default='', type=str, metavar='NAME',
                    help='Image resize interpolation type (overrides model)')
parser.add_argument('--num-classes', type=int, default=1000,
                    help='Number classes in dataset')
parser.add_argument('--checkpoint', default='', type=str, metavar='PATH',
                    help='path to latest checkpoint (default: none)')
parser.add_argument('--pretrained', dest='pretrained', action='store_true',
                    help='use pre-trained model')
parser.add_argument('--no-test-pool', dest='no_test_pool', action='store_true',
                    help='disable test time pool')
parser.add_argument('--save_location', help='place you want to save the model')

def main():
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.pretrained = args.pretrained or not args.checkpoint
    model = create_model(
        args.model,
        num_classes=args.num_classes,
        in_chans=3,
        pretrained=args.pretrained,
        checkpoint_path=args.checkpoint)

    config = resolve_data_config(vars(args), model=model)

    model, test_time_pool = (
        model, False) if args.no_test_pool else apply_test_time_pool(model, config)
    model = model.cuda()

    loader = create_loader(
        ImageDataset(args.data),
        input_size=config['input_size'],
        batch_size=args.batch_size,
        use_prefetcher=True,
        interpolation=config['interpolation'],
        num_workers=args.workers,
        crop_pct=1.0 if test_time_pool else config['crop_pct'])

    model.eval()

    binary_results = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (input, targets) in enumerate(loader):
            input = input.cuda()
            labels = model(input)
            probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(labels, dim=1)
            max_val, predicted_class = probs.max(1)
            binary_results.append((predicted_class == targets).int())

    
    binary_results = torch.cat(binary_results, dim=0)
    
    file_name = '/test.csv'
    temp = args.save_location + file_name
    print('location of the file is:', temp)
    with open(temp, 'w') as out_file:
        filenames = loader.dataset.filenames(basename=True)
        for filename, label in zip(filenames, binary_results.tolist()):
            out_file.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(filename, label))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Collecting the values in `binary_results` and printing to a file reveals that the first 512 predictions (the first 2 batches) are 0s, which is incorrect. Simply changing the loop to:

```
binary_results = []
with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (input, targets) in enumerate(loader):
            input = input.cuda()
            labels = model(input)
            probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(labels, dim=1)
            max_val, predicted_class = probs.max(1)
            binary_results.append((predicted_class == targets).int().cpu())
```

gives correct results. Additionally, simply adding a print statement to the original code fixes the first 256 predictions:

```
binary_results = []
with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (input, targets) in enumerate(loader):
            input = input.cuda()
            labels = model(input)
            probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(labels, dim=1)
            max_val, predicted_class = probs.max(1)
            binary_results.append((predicted_class == targets).int())
        if batch_idx == 0:
            print('Batch results are:', binary_results[0])
```

My pytorch version is 1.12.0, and nvcc --version gives 11.7 (on an Ubuntu 22.04 server).

What is happening? Is some synchronization issue causing this? (Adding `torch.cuda.synchronize()` inside the loop seems to fix it as well!)

Comment: You're calling `.cpu()` in the first loop, not in the second loop.

Comment: I don't know anything about Pytorch, so I don't know what that's for. But the print statement is not the only difference.

Comment: @Barmar I think my code snippets might be slightly unclear. The first snippet has the entire executable, and in the second snippet, I cropped out just the loop and modified it. In the third snippet, I added a print statement to the original loop.

Comment: But one of them has `.int().cpu()`, the others just have `.int()`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, the original code (snippet 1) didn't have a `.cpu()`. I meant that _adding_ a `.cpu()` (snippet 2) gives correct results. In addition, adding a print statement (snippet 3) to the original code without a `.cpu()` also gives correct results. I've made this more explicit in my edit.